# Custom listview setbackground issue

Tags: android

I have custom list view, so when the user clicks an item, I want to change the background of the selected item, but now when I click the example element on position 2, the background has been changed in another position.

```
if (view == null)
{
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_clients_row, null);
    holder.nameClient = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clientName);
    holder.address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addressName);

    view.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}       
    holder.nameClient.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getNameClient());
    holder.address.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getAddressClient());

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"));

        }
    });
return view;
```

Comment: Share your entire adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Add below line in your adapter class

```
private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
```

**Step 2:** Add this line above step 3

```
if(mSelectedPosition == position){
   view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"));
} else {
   view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
}
```

**Step 3:** Change your click method like below

```
   view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             notifyItemChanged(mSelectedPosition);
             mSelectedPosition = position;
             notifyItemChanged(mSelectedPosition);

        }
    });
```

**Step final:** here is the complete modified code.

```
if (view == null)
{
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_clients_row, null);
    holder.nameClient = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clientName);
    holder.address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addressName);

    view.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}       
    holder.nameClient.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getNameClient());
    holder.address.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getAddressClient());

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             notifyItemChanged(mSelectedPosition);
             mSelectedPosition = position;
             notifyItemChanged(mSelectedPosition);

        }
    });

    if(mSelectedPosition == position){
      view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"));
    } else {
       view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    }
return view;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

take one int variable named color in list. First set default color for all element in list.

```
if (view == null)
{
holder = new ViewHolder();
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_clients_row, null);
holder.nameClient = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clientName);
holder.address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addressName);

view.setTag(holder);
} else {
holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}       

view.setBackgroundColor(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getColor());

holder.nameClient.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getNameClient());
holder.address.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).getAddressClient());

view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mDisplayedValues.get(position).setColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"));
        notifyAdapterDataSetChange();
    }
});
return view;
```

in your adapter implement this methods.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: This code i greate, but now another problem, when list view is scroll another item change backround color self

Comment: `ListView` has this drawback on scroll try this using `RecyclerView`.

Comment: but before that try to add above lines in your adapter